# Show formatting in input text html

Tags: javascript, html, input, formatting

Is there anyway to show text in input text and not as hmtl. I mean:
This is</b> bold"/>

`I would like to see in the text input` **This is** bold

`for the output of input text`.

Is there any way to do that? 'Cos I now see this in output: <\b>This is<\b> bold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer? No. Rich text is not a feature of html text input fields.

If you are looking for a full scale What-You-See-Is-What-You-Get (WYSIWYG) editor, than check out [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) or [Aloha](http://www.aloha-editor.org/). They use several iFrames and other trickery to provide rich text as input.

IMO, you should use plain text and a markup language. Take a look at what StackOverflow implements on this very site for asking/answering questions. Its a `<text area>` input that accepts markdown as input and writes an html preview to a separate element on the page.

In the end, the choice depends on your user base. If they are mainly programmers and tech heads, its probably safe to use a markup language and `<text area>` input. If they are the typical service consumer, TinyMCE or something similar might be your best bet for usability.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

In a usual html input (type text or a textarea), you can fill only plain text, the html tags are not rendered.

The only way to do that is to use a wysiwyg editor. Ususally in the form of a JavaScript component to add to your page.

There is a lot of wysiwyg editor on the internet, from the simplest to the most complete.

Comment: That means javascript rendering it. They use javascript, but I dont know how they render the HTML.

Comment: no html is always rendered by the browser, the javascript editors helps you to create something that look like an HTML field but is instead a common HTML element (a div, a frame, etc.) where you can enter formated content.